# iText 7: Seemingly unpredictable behavior of table

Tags: java, scala, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am creating a PDF with several simple tables on it. Each table contains 1-2 cells: an image cell and most of the tables also contain a text cell.

**It works well for all 10 images except for one of them: the image is not rendered.**

Now I took the dimensions of that image's table cells and built a small example (without images and text, just one table with 2 cells) to debug the code:

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.DeviceRgb
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.{PdfDocument, PdfWriter}
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.Border
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.{Cell, Table}

object PdfTablePdf extends App {
  val pdfWriter: PdfWriter = new PdfWriter("/tmp/table.pdf")
  val pdfDocument: PdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter)

  val document = new Document(pdfDocument, new PageSize(2000, 3000))

  val table = new Table(1)

  val cellA = new Cell()
    .setMargin(0)
    .setPadding(0)
    .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
  cellA.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(0, 255, 0))
  cellA.setWidth(1331.1774900609144f)
  cellA.setHeight(49.71372725227489f)
    // replace that value by 49f or 50f and the pdf will be rendered as expected

  table.addCell(cellA)

  val cellB = new Cell()
    .setMargin(0)
    .setPadding(0)
    .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)
  cellB.setBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(0, 0, 255))
  cellB.setWidth(1331.1774900609144f)
  cellB.setHeight(994.2745450454978f)
  table.addCell(cellB)

  document.add(table)

  document.close()

}
```

And though it looks harmless, it still shows some strange behavior: If I set the height of the first cell to the calculated value 49.71372725227489f, the second cell is not rendered on the first page.

[image: 49.71372725227489f]

If I set the height of the first cell to 49 or 50, the output is as expected (second cell directly below first cell).

[image: 50f]

I did not believe my eyes, but it really behaved like that. And I made sure it is not a bug in a certain PDF viewer.

**How can that behavior be explained and how can I make sure the table is rendered correctly?**

Dependencies in `build.sbt`:

```
name := "pdftablepdf"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value,
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
  "com.itextpdf" % "kernel" % "7.1.1",
  "com.itextpdf" % "io" % "7.1.1",
  "com.itextpdf" % "layout" % "7.1.1",
  "com.itextpdf" % "forms" % "7.1.1",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug indeed looks very strange, but luckily it has already been fixed in `7.1.2` version. While not having been publicly announced just yet and not uploaded to Maven Central as well, the binaries of the new release are already available at [iText Artifactory](http://repo.itextsupport.com).

To add the repository in Maven, use the following configuration:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>itext-releases</id>
      <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
      <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

To add it into Scala build tool file you probably need the following command:

```
resolvers += "iText Releases" at "https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases"
```

Comment: Many thanks. Now it works. Before I tried tables, I had tried `Div`s, `Paragraph`s and floating images to place the page content. I could achieve the same result as now, but a different image disappeared suddenly when it was by a certain angle.

Comment: I am really curious how suchlike effects can be that insistent, thus I took a quick look at the release change log (btw. that change log shows me how much progress is made in the itext7 project): https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases . But I could not spot the relevant change. Can you nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: @ideaboxer please don't expect absolutely every bug that was fixed to be listed in the change log :)

Comment: Ok :-) Still I am interested. Since I am currently using the library for non-commercial projects, I am interested in getting to know the source code in order to give back some support in the form of pull requests sooner or later. I see this question as a great entry point for contributing.